# Hibernate SchemaExport and Persistence unit

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence-unit

A followup question to my previous question: [Generate an SQL DB creation script with Hibernate 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014247/generate-an-sql-db-creation-script-with-hibernate-4)

The goal is to have a command line tool able to generate a file with the SQL schema of a given persistence unit (similarly to the hibernatetool-hbm2ddl Ant task present in the Hibernate Tools).

This, as per the answer to my previous question, can be achieved with `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport`.

Instead of adding all the entities to the `Configuration` (as suggested in the previous answer) I would like to specify a `PersistenceUnit`.

Is it possible to *add* a persistence unit to an Hibernate `Configuration`?

Something like

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put( "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" );
...
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "persistentUnitName", properties );
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

... missing part ...

SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport( configuration );
schemaExport.setOutputFile( "schema.sql" );
...
```

**Edit** as requested in the comments a sample `persistence.xml`. Each class is annotated with `@Entity`

```
<persistence
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0"
>

    <persistence-unit
        name="doiPersistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="JTA"
    >

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/doi</jta-data-source>


        <class>ch.ethz.id.wai.doi.bo.Doi</class>
        [...]
        <class>ch.ethz.id.wai.doi.bo.DoiPool</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql"                     value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql"                   value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet"           value="utf8" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: so you want to save the `config.addAnnotatedClass(MyMappedPojo1.class);` lines?

Comment: @yair yes I would like to avoid to specify all the classes manually (and avoid to hard-code them). I know I could parse the persistence.xml file but I suspect there is an easier way.

Comment: I think you're missing also passing dialect into configuration - it will fail when SchemaExport is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if your classes are mapped via xml mappings (`hbm`s) - you can add the documnets or jar files that include the xmls straight to the `Configuration` instance using `config.addJar(myJarFile)` and `config.add(myXmlFile)`.

However, if you want your *annotated* classes to be scanned - I know of no such straightforward option through Hibernate (`addPackage` adds metadata and *not* classes).

You *may* implement your own scan logic and add all annotated classes with `config.addAnnotatedClass(myAnnotatedClass)` (or perhaps do it per specific packages you know for containing you ORM classes and thus maybe save some time).

**UPDATE 2**

Oh, even better, you can just iterate the persistence unit's `ManagedType`s via `getManagedTypes()`:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( unitName, config.getProperties() );
final Set<ManagedType<?>> managedTypes =
    entityManagerFactory.getMetamodel().getManagedTypes();
    for ( ManagedType<?> managedType : managedTypes ) {
    final Class<?> javaType = managedType.getJavaType();
    config.addAnnotatedClass( javaType );
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can determine the `PersistenceUnit` of each `Entity` - *without parsing the xml* - by checking against the relevant `EntityManagerFactory`:

```
Class aClass = ... // get the class from your scanning
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( unitName, config.getProperties() );
ManagedType<?> managedType = null;
try {
    managedType = entityManagerFactory.getMetamodel().managedType( aClass );
} catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
    // happens when aClass isn't a type managed by the persistence unit
}
if ( managedType != null ) {
    config.addAnnotatedClass( aClass );
}
```

Make sure to use different `Configuration` instances for each persistence unit. Otherwise, annotated classes would just accumulate and so also the DDL.

I tried it and it worked great - printed two distinct DDLs for two different persistence units.

Comment: the classes are annotated. Scanning the jar files for annotations could be an option but I would still have to parse the parse the persistence.xml files to know to which persistence unit a given \@Entity belongs

Comment: @Matteo could you please post your `persistence.xml`?

Comment: there is no single persistence.xml but many of them (hence the need for my tool) I will add one example.

Comment: Ok but to get the classes I have to list all the classes present in the classpath or did I get it wrong? I was hoping for a way to simply list the classes managed by a given persistence unit but your solution will do :-)

Comment: @Matteo seems you're right, there _is_ a better solution. See again **UPDATE 2**.