# Hibernate forward Engineering

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, forward-engineer

I want to implement a simple application Hibernate forward engineering concept.  Where If I make any changes to Hibernate Entities then Hibernate should automatically make specific changes to the database columns.

For example:

If I add a new field in Hibernate Entity (`POJO`), then a new column should be added to the DB table. (This should happen when I restart tomcat).

Is this possible?

Comment: can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014247/generate-an-sql-db-creation-script-with-hibernate-4

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using hibernate configuration property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`. set this property value to **update** to reflect changes from POJO to database. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do?answertab=votes#tab-top) for more information.